# React static files not rendering inside html

Tags: reactjs, strapi, koa, shopify-app, shopify-template

I’ve got stuck in rendering React HTML in liquid files.

I have totally 3 apps.

```
Strapi - https://my-api.com
React App - https://my-react-app.com
shopify store - https://shopify-store.com

GET https://shopify-store.com  ->>  GET https://my-api.com/api/get-form
```

The above URL request is sent by the Shopify store app to my strapi server and I have to return an HTML.

```
/api/*/controller/fileName.js

const { data } = await axios.get('https://my-react-app.com/form-page');
// the above data contains react's html
ctx.send(data); // returning react's HTML to shopify store
```

I have done the above method and it returns HTML but it is not rendering Html in the UI.
If you notice from the screenshot, the `<div id="main"></div>` is empty.

[image]

Please help me to find a solution to render HTML…

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your app change liquid file by Script tag api.

return your html as string like

```
"<html><body></body></html>"
```

please provide more details of file where you receive html and set it to shopify store.